Расстановка точек над буквой «ё»
Если во всем тексте только в одном месте буква "ё" выделена характерными точками, то не обязывает ли это проставить эти точки во всем тексте, где есть эта буква без точек?

ну желательно, но для этого нужно мизинчиком или безымянчиком тянуться до ё каждый раз, иногда лень.

Чтобы получить Ё, проставляем характерные точки над Е? Во всём тексте? Врагу не пожелаешь.

Здесь есть серьезные люди?)  Но характерные точки — хорошо сказано! Это, наверное, тоже юмор)

• Вот мнение кандидата филологических наук, главного редактора портала «Грамота.ру», члена орфографической комиссии РАН Владимира Пахомова:

Одним из самых дискуссионных вопросов новых правил стало использование буквы «ё». Эксперт заверил, что эта буква не исчезнет, а ее написание по-прежнему останется факультативным. Она будет использоваться в учебниках по русскому языку, в словарях и энциклопедиях, в именах собственных, а также там, где буква влияет на произношение и смысл слова. Как, например, в словах «совершенный» и «совершённый».

• Вот пример из «Петра Первого» Алексея Толстого: Вот, скажут, такого господина нам Бог послал, при таком-то передохнем... (см.).
В оригинале имелось в виду «передохнём». У издателей чаще всего — «передохнем».
Смысл-то ведь разный, правда?
• Вот известнейшие имена: Афанасий Фет и Мирей Матье (правильно — Фёт и Матьё).
● Вот вывод: нет надобности проставлять эти точки во всем тексте.
Буква ё, скорее всего, была напечатана (написана) по одной из указанных причин.
